# How can I open an excel file using openFileDialog

Tags: c#

I am having a hard time figuring this out.  I would like to do on button click event to open a `filedialog` window in which the user will select an excel file and the file will get open in excel.

I have created the `filebox` and I am able to get the excel to open a new file,but I can't figure out how to get the two to mesh.

what I am trying to use is as follows,

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection; 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
           System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
           MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
           sr.Close();
        }
   }
}
```

and I was going to use this to open excel

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare excel and wb as fields of your form. Something like

```
partial class MyForm : Form
{
  private Excel.Application _excel;
  private Excel.Workbook _wb;
  // and so on
}
```

Then you should replace

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
```

with

```
_excel = new Excel.Application();
_wb = _excel.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: Why?  Is it because his `excel` and `wb` objects drop out of scope?

Comment: Yep. If you declare them inside the event handler they are out of scope as soon as you leave the handler.

Comment: i get "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(string, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object, object)'

Comment: There were two nasty typos in the last piece of code of my answer. Maybe that's causing the error.

Comment: there are no errors now. However nothing happens when selecting the file

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: upon selecting the file and clicking OK, excel should open with the selected workbook.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30729/discussion-between-otterbaub-and-venerik)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot chat. Firewall is blocking it. 

You probably have to add _excel.Visible = true;

Comment: Checked my program manager and i had about excel open in 20 instances so i think the visible idea is the next front to attack

Answer (score 4):

Just pass the filename from the open file dialog to the Excel application.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection; 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: all that happens when i run this code is the form freezes for 5-10 sec and then nothing.